# Page region CSS class not applied

Tags: theming

I am working with Drupal 8.5-x, I am trying to render HTML with bootstrap classes, but I am having trouble. Here is my problem:

I have highlighted (region) and content (region). I am trying to add a `<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">` with highlighted region but to no avail.

I have:

```
{# Highlighted #}
  {%
    set highlighted_classes = [
      page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second ? 'col-sm-6',
      page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-sm-9 col-md-8',
      page.sidebar_second and page.sidebar_first is empty ? 'col-sm-12',
      page.sidebar_first is empty and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-sm-12'
    ]
  %}

{# Content #}
  {%
    set content_classes = [
      page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second ? 'col-sm-6',
      page.sidebar_first and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-sm-12 col-md-12',
      page.sidebar_second and page.sidebar_first is empty ? 'col-sm-12',
      page.sidebar_first is empty and page.sidebar_second is empty ? 'col-sm-12'
    ]
  %}

  <section {{ highlighted_attributes.addClass(highlighted_classes) }}> 
  <section {{ content_attributes.addClass(content_classes) }}>
```

when rendered, I get

```
<section>
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12>
```

but I was expecting

```
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<section class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
```

I am lost as to where I could have gone wrong.
My info file is as follows:

```
    regions:
  navigation: 'Navigation'
  navigation_collapsible: 'Navigation (Collapsible)'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer_first: 'First Footer'
  footer_second: 'Second Footer'
  footer_third: 'Third Footer'
  footer_fourth: 'Fourth Footer'
  footer_fifth: 'Fifth Footer'
  page_top: 'Page top'
  page_bottom: 'Page bottom'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I read on attributes: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates

The attribute I was referencing 'highlighted_attributes' was blank. I just added a simpler solution, by referecing to the example of the API:

```
{% set classes = [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ] %}

<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}></div>
```